# PyTorch : How to properly create a list of nn.Linear()

Tags: python, pytorch

I have created a class that has nn.Module as subclass.

In my class, I have to create N number of linear transformation, where N is given as class parameters.

I therefore proceed as follow :

```
    self.list_1 = []

    for i in range(N):
        self.list_1.append(nn.Linear(self.x, 1, bias=mlp_bias))
```

In the forward method, i call these matrices (with list_1[i]) and concat the results.

Two things :

1)

Even though I use model.cuda(), these Linear transform are used on cpu and i get the following error :

> RuntimeError: Expected object of type Variable[torch.cuda.FloatTensor] but found type Variable[torch.FloatTensor] for argument #1 'mat2'

I have to do

```
self.list_1.append(nn.Linear(self.x, 1, bias=mlp_bias).cuda())
```

This is not required if instead, i do :

```
self.nn = nn.Linear(self.x, 1, bias=mlp_bias)
```

and then use self.nn directly.

2)

For more obvious reason, when I print(model) in my main, the Linear matrices in my list arent printed.

Is there any other way. maybe using bmm ? I find it less easy, and i actually want to have my N results separately.

Thank you in advance,

M

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You can use `nn.ModuleList` to wrap your list of linear layers as explained [here](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/when-should-i-use-nn-modulelist-and-when-should-i-use-nn-sequential/5463)

```
self.list_1 = nn.ModuleList(self.list_1)
```